# ASP.NET Core Web API - POST method throws exception of duplicate (autoincremented) PK

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I encountered odd behaviour with such a code:

```
// POST: /tutors 
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTutor([FromBody] TutorViewModel vmTutor) {

            if (vmTutor == null)
                return new StatusCodeResult(500); // Internal Server Error 

            try
            {
                // check if the Person with given personId exists 
                Person person = await _unitOfWork.People.GetAsync(vmTutor.PersonId);
                if (person == null) throw new Exception("Given Person doesn't exists.");

                // create new Tutor entity for given Person entity 
                var newTutor = new Tutor
                {
                    Description = vmTutor.Description,
                    Qualifications = vmTutor.Qualifications,
                    IsSuperTutor = vmTutor.IsSuperTutor,
                    //PersonId = vmTutor.PersonId
                    Person = person
                };

                // Add new Tutor to DBContext and save changes 
                await _unitOfWork.Tutors.AddAsync(newTutor);
                _unitOfWork.Complete();

                vmTutor.TutorId = newTutor.TutorId;

                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTutor), new { tutorId = vmTutor.TutorId }, vmTutor);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                return new ObjectResult(new { error = e.Message }); 
            }
        }
```

Above code works fine and adds new Tutor for given Person to database, generating correct TutorId for Tutor entity. But when I've changed association of `newTutor.Person = person` to `newTutor.PersonId = vmTutor.PersonId` than it stops working and throws exception like below:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Tutors' with unique index 'IX_Tutors_PersonId'. The duplicate key value is (6).
      The statement has been terminated.
```

As I remember the same code works fine when there was its **not-async version**, i.e. like below:

```
// POST: /tutors 
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateTutor([FromBody] TutorViewModel vmTutor) {

            if (vmTutor == null)
                return new StatusCodeResult(500); // Internal Server Error 

            try
            {
                // check if the Person with given personId exists 
                Person person =  _unitOfWork.People.Get(vmTutor.PersonId);
                if (person == null) throw new Exception("Given Person doesn't exists.");

                // create new Tutor entity for given Person entity 
                var newTutor = new Tutor
                {
                    Description = vmTutor.Description,
                    Qualifications = vmTutor.Qualifications,
                    IsSuperTutor = vmTutor.IsSuperTutor,
                    PersonId = vmTutor.PersonId
                    //Person = person
                };

                // Add new Tutor to DBContext and save changes 
                _unitOfWork.Tutors.AddAsync(newTutor);
                _unitOfWork.Complete();

                vmTutor.TutorId = newTutor.TutorId;

                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTutor), new { tutorId = vmTutor.TutorId }, vmTutor);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                return new ObjectResult(new { error = e.Message }); 
            }
        }
```

Could you explain why I cannot assign foreign key PersonId in Tutor entity directly while I am using async version? And explain me when this async version should be preferred instead of casual entity CRUD operations?

Thx for help and explanation.

Comment: The exception does not mention a conflict with your PK. It is throwing error on `IX_Tutors_PersonId` which appears to be a unique index.

Comment: Usually PK or FK are Unique? But There isn't any record with such key value like PersonId in database.  Insertion when using Person object association with the same id works correctly. I also remember that this method works fine when there wasn't this async/await modifiers and explicit checking for Person existance in database using _unitOfWork.People.GetAsync() method